# How to speed up C++ DirectX putting pixel

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I'm making a game using DirectX 9.
I use my own PutPixel function:

```
void Graphics::BeginFrame()
{
pDev->Clear(0,NULL,D3DCLEAR_TARGET,D3DCOLOR_XRGB(114,196,207),1.0f,10);
pBackBuffer->LockRect(&rect,NULL,NULL);
}
void Graphics::EndFrame()
{
pBackBuffer->UnlockRect();
pDev->Present(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
}
void Graphics::PutPixel(int x,int y,D3DCOLOR rgb)
{
((D3DCOLOR *)rect.pBits)[x+(rect.Pitch>>2)*y]=rgb;
}
```

where pDev is LPD3DDEVICE9,pBackBuffer is IDirect3DSurface9 * and rect is D3DLOCKED_RECT.
It is pretty good without background image,but it really slows down when I add one.
I want to be able to add background image without slowing the game down.
I tried using a memory buffer for storing data and then memcpy it to rect.pBits inside EndFrame,but it didn't help much.I need the optimized version of putting pixel.
Help please
Thanks

Comment: Any reason you must draw background image with your own PutPixel?

Answer (score 2):

First, I suspect you are going about the whole thing in a wrong way. Writing pixels ino the frame buffer by hand is a very 1990s way of writing a game. DirectX has functions for blitting entire images to the screen automatically, even with hardware acceleration. It will probably be not only faster, but also easier and more convenient to use them.

That said, there are several sources of slowness here:

1. Caching: Frame buffer memory might have different (i.e., worse) caching behaviour compared to main memory. As using `memcpy` didn't help, this doesn't seam to be a big problem in your case.
2. Bus transfer: Data needs to get from the CPU to the GPU; this is slower than doing things the "modern way" (i.e. putting your images together using accelerated GPU functions), but your bus will definitely be fast enough to transfer one screenfull of pixels per frame.
3. Per-pixel arithmetic: You're doing the address calculations over and over again for each pixel. However, I see no easy way to fix this without breaking abstraction and making everything harder to read and more error prone (i.e. no PutPixel function, just pointer arithmetic all over the place).
4. Function call overhead: Calling a function is more work than actually putting a pixel. Try putting your PutPixel implementation into a header file and marking it `inline`. If your compiler is good, it might even fix number 3 for you.

### Overall recommendation

Think hard about not doing it at all and using higher level functions. If you want to stick with PutPixel, try addressing (4) above. If that doesn't help, the problem might be somewhere else entirely.